# Web scraping a table into a pandas DataFrame from fbref.com

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to to web scrape all of the player stats for each team in the Argentinian soccer league: https://fbref.com/en/comps/21/stats/Primera-Division-Stats. My issue is that I am scraping all of the team data, and cannot figure out how to get just the individual player data.

I am pretty new to web scraping and pandas. I am not sure if I am just missing something or approaching the problem incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my block of code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_argentina_standard = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/21/stats/Primera-Division-Stats'

data = requests.get(url_argentina_standard)
standard_stats = soup.find_all(class_='stats_table')
temp = pd.read_html(str(standard_stats))[0]
argentina_standard_df = pd.DataFrame(temp)]]
```

This code returns the team data, but shows there are only 2 tables that have the class_='stats_table', none of them being the player stats table.

```
standard_stats = soup.find_all(class_='stats_table')[0]
standard_stats = soup.find_all(class_='stats_table')[1]
```

I have also tried switching up the find_all() and using something like find_all(id='stats_squads_standards_for', which is the table id of the one I am trying to get.

Ideally, I am would like to be able to switch the link to another teams division such as https://fbref.com/en/comps/56/stats/Austrian-Bundesliga-Stats, which has the same formatting.

Comment: You did not indicate what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem, in my opinion, is that the `table` you are looking for is commented out ([kind of objects](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-objects)) and thus basically "invisible".

Regardless, no `BeautifulSoup` object has been created in the example code that could be accessed via `soup.find_all(class_='stats_table')`.

The easiest way to solve the problem without going into depth with regard to `BeautifulSoup` is to replace/remove the comment characters that lead in and out:

```
requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')
```

Then you could use `pandas.read_html()` with attribute parameters:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url= 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/21/stats/Primera-Division-Stats'
pd.read_html(
    requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')
    ,attrs={'id':'stats_standard'}
)[0]
```

Comment: That worked awesome, thank you. I was wondering if you actually could go deeper and explain it. I might be able to update my question so that it answers the issue more broadly, and not just specifically for fbref.com.